# Unanswered - My Tags shows wrong content on iOS

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The option "unanswered - my tags" shows the wrong content some times. Some of the tags in the questions listed I have explicitly 'blocked' on the desktop website.

[image]

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.2.1 (Build 13D15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next prod API build. (No update required.)

Caching was taking place on a method rather than an account level, so if someone looked at "Unanswered (My Tags)" just before you *and* none of the questions in that list had been modified, you saw their results.  Now this method will always be cached based on method and account.